# Angularjs ng-disabled always stays disabled

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Note: I have bare knowledge on AngularJS.

I have a very basic script which uses AngularJS. It is a simple login form that I want to make dynamic.It is a template file that I copy-pasted in order to implement login page in my Security token service (Identity Server 3 by leastprivilege).

So, this is how it looks like:

```
<div class="page-header">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="../Content/Images/logo.png" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="row" ng-show="model.errorMessage">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div ng-init="model.LoginButtonClicked = false" class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Error:</strong>
            {{model.errorMessage}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" ng-show="model.loginUrl">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form name="form" method="post" action="{{model.loginUrl}}">
                    <anti-forgery-token token="model.antiForgery"></anti-forgery-token>

                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <input required name="username" id="username" type="text" class="form-control" ng-change="model.errorMessage = false; model.LoginButtonClicked = false" placeholder="Username" ng-model="model.username" maxlength="100">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <input required id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" ng-change="model.errorMessage = false; model.LoginButtonClicked = false" placeholder="Password" ng-model="model.password" maxlength="100" autocomplete="off" focus-if="model.username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group login-remember" ng-show="model.allowRememberMe">
                            <label for="rememberMe">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe" ng-model="model.rememberMe" value="true">
                                <strong>Remember me</strong>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button ng-disabled="model.LoginButtonClicked" class="btn btn-login btn-primary" ng-init="model.LoginButtonClicked = false" ng-click="model.LoginButtonClicked = true">
                                <span ng-show="model.LoginButtonClicked && model.username && model.password" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh spinning"></span>
                                <span ng-show="!model.LoginButtonClicked || !model.username || !model.password">Login</span>    
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li ng-repeat="link in model.additionalLinks"><a ng-href="{{link.href}}">{{link.text}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!---<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 external-providers" ng-show="model.externalProviders.length">-->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <!--  <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">External Login</h3> -->
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="list-inline" style="text-align:center">
            <li ng-repeat="provider in model.externalProviders">
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{provider.href}}">{{provider.text}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!---- </div> -->
</div>
```

The important stuff is here:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button ng-disabled="model.LoginButtonClicked" class="btn btn-login btn-primary" ng-init="model.LoginButtonClicked = false" ng-click="model.LoginButtonClicked = true">
        <span ng-show="model.LoginButtonClicked && model.username && model.password" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh spinning"></span>
        <span ng-show="!model.LoginButtonClicked || !model.username || !model.password">Login</span>    
    </button>
</div>
```

and here:

```
<div class="row" ng-show="model.errorMessage">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div ng-init="model.LoginButtonClicked = false" class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Error:</strong>
            {{model.errorMessage}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The idea is to have a spinner while loading the request and if validation errors happen - remove the spinner and go back to initial state. I am manipulating that through the property **model.LoginButtonClicked** . That is why I am trying to take advantage of it in my disable functionality (Once the spinner is there I want to make the button disabled - want to prevent repetitive clicks).

For some reason, it always stays as additional attribute to the button element like this: **disabled = "disabled"**

How can I achieve my goal and have it diabled only when **model.LoginButtonClicked**  is equal to true?

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me ([here](https://plnkr.co/edit/2T6budKtWXVHsiamplgo?p=preview)). Add a plunker of your code and I can take a look.

Comment: @WilliamHampshire it has to come back to 'enabled' state but it doesn't. That is the actual issue that I have.

Comment: It's hard to say exactly without you posting your working code example like I said, but check out my answer and let me know if that works for you! (it's working for me)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but you might just need a `$scope.$apply` if you think your code is correct...

All you have to do in a situation like this is set the disabled variable to true once the button is clicked, do your logic, then set the disabled variable back to false once that is completed.

HTML:

```
<button ng-disabled="loginButtonClicked" ng-click="buttonClicked()">click me</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
  $scope.loginButtonClicked = false;

  $scope.buttonClicked = function() {
    //set the button clicked to true
    $scope.loginButtonClicked = true;

    //do whatever you need to do here ($http request, etc)

    //setTimeout is only to mock the time it would take to do the server call
    setTimeout(function() {
      $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.loginButtonClicked = false;
      });
    }, 2000);
  }
```

Working Code: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/eHvD0Y84NRbS1UwzqkwU?p=preview)

Comment: I don't really have access to the scope. I manipulate everything via the html delcarations.

Comment: Can you please put your code in a [plunker](https://plunker.co/)? Something like model.LoginButtonClicked means that it is a scope variable (technically $scope.model.LoginButtonClicked. It doesn't appear you're super familiar with angular, but as you can see from my example (with plunker) that it works fine for me.

Comment: What you see is everything that I have. Just that HTML.

Comment: We need the javascript code though too. And not just on the page, but **working** on a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/)...